# Use a pretty printer to write a to_string function

Tags: ocaml, tostring, pretty-print

I have defined a big pretty printer `pp: out_channel -> t -> unit` over a big type `t`. Therefore, I can use it like `Printf.fprintf stdout "%a" x` where `x: t`, or chain printing like `Printf.fprintf chan "%a" pp x` where `chan: out_channel`.

Now I need  to convert what is printed to a string or a text. Does anyone know if there is a way to leverage/use the function `pp` rather than writing a function `to_string: t -> unit` from scratch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Format.asprintf` should suit your needs, if you `pp` is implemented for `Format.formatter` type instead of `out_channel`. The `Format.formatter` is a more general type and should be preferred to the concrete `out_channel`.  In fact, a sort of a standard type for pretty printer is the `Format.formatter -> 'a -> unit` type, at least it is required by the `#install_printer` directive in OCaml toplevel, debugger and other facilities. Functions of the same type are used in `Core` library to implement `Pretty_printer` interface.

So, if you will reimplement your `pp` function to work with the `Format` module (usually for this it would be enough just to `open Format` module), then you can reuse it. The functions, that print to `out_channel` module can't be retargetered to print into string. So it is better not to write them.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work you need something that looks to OCaml like an out channel, but keeps the data in a string (or buffer) instead. There's nothing like this in OCaml, unfortunately.

Comment: There is, that's what `Format.formatter` is for. See answer above, and that's why everyone use a pp function of type `Format.formatter -> t -> unit`.

Comment: What I meant by "looks like" is that it has the type "out_channel". There's nothing like that. But you are surely right about the way to handle the problem, also pointed out by ivg.